# How to correctly configure SVN for hudson (jenkins) continous integration system?

Tags: macos, hudson, jenkins

I'm configuring a jenkins to build my XCode project on MacOS 10.6.6. For this purpose i have installed latest tomcat container and latest jenkins as ROOT.war. All works fine except adding subversion integration :(. After creating a new project in jenkins i selected "subversion" in "Source Code Management" and entered my repository URL same way i use in command-line subversion tool:

```
https://svn.mydomain.local/main/project/trunk
```

Unfortunately, it is not working with a strange error "authentication cancelled":
[image]

The 'details' log looks like this:

```
Unable to access https://svn.mydomain.local/main/project/trunk : svn: authentication cancelled 
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: authentication cancelled
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getNextAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:257)
    at hudson.scm.FilterSVNAuthenticationManager.getNextAuthentication(FilterSVNAuthenticationManager.java:39)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:552)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:275)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:263)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:97)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:1842)
```

The most strange thing: if i click "enter credentials" and enter my login and password, Jenkins reports back "Authentication was successful. Information is stored in Hudson now." but it's still red "unable to access" and checkout error on build :(.

Command-line `svn co` works fine for both user and root accounts with all credentials cached. Maybe anyone who has a hudson on macos experience can drop a few hints what to do?

Comment: This is a Jenkins bug. Please see and vote here at [Jenkins 8059](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8059)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to check the basic setup, does the user running tomcat/jenkins have write access to the .hudson directory and below, specifically to hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml?

Additionally, [someone else](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/svn-authentication-cancelled-issue-with-Hudson-td1015075.html) had success with setting `-Dsvnkit.http.methods=Basic,NTLM` in the JAVA_ARGS.

Comment: Impressive. Adding the specified string to JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh solves the problem! Just out of curiosity - why such problem is not fixed in jenkins itself? No one uses subversion over HTTPS?

Comment: This seems to be a common problem when using SVNKit with NTLM authentication. [This](http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.subversion.javasvn.user/2008-04/msg00049.html) is the only, though somewhat unsatisfying, explanation I've found.

Answer (score 1):

In Hudson configuration -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced Tab -> Make sure your HTTP Proxy configurations are properly set.

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog ([blog.vinodsingh](http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2009/08/hudson-svn-authentication-cancelled.html)) entry posted by someone who faced a very similar issue. He just removed the `.subversion` directory and it solved the problem.

Comment: I have found this blog entry too. Unfortunately, `sudo rm -rf &#96;sudo find / -name .subversion 2>/dev/null&#96;` changes nothing :(.

Comment: It didn't work for me either. I don't know how to solve this issue. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You need to do an additional step after removing .subversion folder and that's to checkout the repo locally so that Jenkins can load the svn cached credentials. You can see a better explanation in my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464993/jenkins-cannot-acces-to-svn-https/19598786#19598786

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue on only one job, but not when configuring the job, when a post-commit script try to trigger a build :

```
27 oct. 2011 17:57:45 hudson.scm.SubversionRepositoryStatus doNotifyCommit
WARN: Failed to handle Subversion commit notification
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: authentication cancelled
[...]
```

Inspecting the job configuration reveals that the "Included regions" parameters wasn't set correctly :
trunk/src/dir

Corrected this params with :
/trunk/src/dir

makes jenkins no more having the issue