# Which plugin is required to use hudson with svn?

Tags: svn, hudson, hudson-plugins

I am new to hudson and i'm using SVN ,I want to know to use hudson with svn whether we have to use any plugin? If yes which plugin ?

Comment: Check this

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298152/how-to-correctly-configure-svn-for-hudson-jenkins-continous-integration-system

Answer (score 2):

It is completely possible to use SVN with Hudson, there is the [SVN plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin), but as it is said in the doc  :

> This plugin adds the Subversion support (via SVNKit) to Hudson.This
>   plugin is bundled inside hudson.war.

So, you have nothing to do to add it, once you've installed hudson, you have the SVN plugin.