# Jenkins cannot access to SVN (https://)

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

I created Jenkins project that have files on SVN (https://repo.xxx.xxx/svn/priv/projectname; certificate is self-signed). My problem is that Jenkins have empty workspace for this project (only .svn) and it cannot connect to SVN repo. The error number is:

```
**svn: E175002**
```

Jenkins **ver. 1.521**

I founded somewhere that I should use  **-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3** as a parameter but I don't know where to put it (I'm using Jenkins with Tomcat on server).

Stack trace:

```
INFO: Failed to access subversion repository https://repo.xxx.xxx/svn/priv/projectname
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/priv/mgrzeslowski/flatmanager failed
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:379)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:364)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:708)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:628)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1018)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:2038)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(SubversionSCM.java:1972)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor392.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:297)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:160)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:684)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:777)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:239)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:684)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:777)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:239)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:684)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:777)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:586)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:217)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/priv/mgrzeslowski/flatmanager failed
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
... 82 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/priv/mgrzeslowski/flatmanager'
svn: E175002: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
at      org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
at  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:754)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
... 81 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/priv/mgrzeslowski/flatmanager'
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:752)
... 82 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:109)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:505)
... 82 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1977)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1093)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.sendData(HTTPConnection.java:313)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:168)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:460)
... 82 more
```

Comment: I was facing this exact same problem. After some additional research I discovered that you can see this error as a result of SSLstrip, which our work employs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy. I connected to SVN repo from my computer (in command line) as user jenkins. I accepted all certificates permanently (p). This created directory ~/.subversion. I copied this directory to server (wget). And from now everything works just fine.

Comment: I just followed what you mentioned.. But unfortunately still getting the error. Anything more needs to done?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like Jenkins uses svn credentials cache to authenticate. Those credentials are stored in the ~/.subversion/auth folder. I was struggling because of this and the solution i found was to clean up ~/.subversion/auth folder and then checkout from the console of the machine Jenkins is installed on, append the username Jenkins will use as a parameter. Something like this

```
svn checkout --username jenkins-svn-user http://svn.server/repo
```

That will ask for the credentials of the *jenkins-svn-user* and will store them locally so that Jenkins can use them. Then you can check on your job configuration whether it worked or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: For windows, the files are located in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Subversion\auth`. Another solution is to modify your subversion config and uncomment **"store-passwords = no"** or to use this flag when manually running svn: **--no-auth-cache**

Comment: @Seth Just tried all these suggestions on Debian 3.2.51-1 with everything updated to the latest: does not work. :(

Answer (score 3):

Old question, I know. Maybe someone else will find this, though?

I had this problem for awhile, before realizing that I hadn't downloaded the SVN plugin. Even though SVN appears as an option in the Source Code Management section of the configuration screen in Jenkins, the plugin wasn't installed. Hence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272158