# SVN checkout not working for Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I installed Jenkins for MAC-OSX and when I try to put the SVN repository link I get the following error

```
FAILED: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/branches/PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/PRIME_JAVA_API/PrimeCoreServices failed
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/branches/PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/PRIME_JAVA_API/PrimeCoreServices failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:379)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:364)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:708)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:628)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1018)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.postCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1939)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doPostCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1884)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:297)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:685)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:239)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:685)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:239)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:685)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:587)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/branches/PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/PRIME_JAVA_API/PrimeCoreServices failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: OPTIONS request failed on '/PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/branches/PRIME_SOURCE_CODE/PRIME_JAVA_API/PrimeCoreServices'
svn: E170001: HTTP proxy authorization failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:748)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: svn: E170001: HTTP proxy authorization failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:568)
    ... 63 more
```

The above error is not allowing me to move ahead and am not able to understand how to proceed.

Please help.

Comment: It says HTTP proxy authorization failed. Have you provided your svn credentials?

Comment: @ShivaKumar Yes I have provided that but still its now working :(

Comment: Is it a newly configured job or it started failing suddenly? At times I observed that for old jobs, after deleting the existing workspace completely on the slave, SVN could take the complete checkout without problem.

Comment: No its  a recent one. How can I configure the Proxy for Jenkins ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11272158/463824 See this. I guess this is where you have to configure. You need admin permissions though

Comment: Where you able to solve this? was a proxy issue? I have a similar issue. I changed the user jenkins used to connect to svn and it no longer can authenticate. Not even with the old credentials configuration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in order to solve it you need to remove the ~/.subversion folder and checkout the repo locally so that Jenkins can load the svn cached credentials. You can see a better explanation by reading my answer to a similar question [Jenkins cannot acces to SVN (https://)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464993/jenkins-cannot-acces-to-svn-https/19598786#19598786)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as above. It turned out that the svn credentials in Jenkins had been erased and I had to re-enter the svn username and password in the credentials section. Works now!